# Laravel ORM Array to String Conversion

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

Laravel 5.3, PHP 5.6
Fresh `laravel new` project, minimal configuration.

I have made a simple migration and model, and am trying to seed data into it via `php artisan tinker`.

My migration looks like this:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatesFooTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('foo', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('foo', 20);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('foo');
    }
}
```

When I run `php artisan migrate` the database populates just fine.

The corresponding model is simple:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Foo extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'foo';

    protected $fillable = ['foo'];

}
```

I have a ModelFactory as well:

```
$factory->define(App\Foo::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {

    return [
        'foo' => $faker->email,
    ];
});
```

Tinker does what I think it should do when I try to `make` a flyer from the factory:

```
>>> factory('App\Foo')->make();
=> App\Foo {#696
     foo: "morgan39@gmail.com",
```

But when I try to hit the database, Eloquent fails to wrap the query values in a string:

```
>>> $foo = factory('App\Foo')->create();
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'foo' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `foo` (`foo`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (jakayla62@streich.org, 2016-09-06 23:59:03, 2016-09-06 23:59:03))'
```

Nothing like this on Google.  Any ideas?

(Edited to show the same problem with a much simpler example)

Comment: Are you sure it's not  because you haven't set your fillable fields on the model?

Comment: @pseudoanime Just added the $fillable fields (edited above).  Same result.

Answer (score 14):

Some of the faker methods return their result as an array, as a default. For example:

```
$faker->words(3)
```

would return:

```
array('porro', 'sed', 'magni')
```

To return the result as a string you can pass `true` as the second argument for some methods, as in the previous example using the `words` method:

```
$faker->words(3, true)
```

returns:

```
"porro sed magni"
```

As described in the [readme](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker#basic-usage):

```
words($nb = 3, $asText = false)    // array('porro', 'sed', 'magni')
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.  The problem was the faker library.  Apparently when you explicitly cast `(string)$faker->whatever` it fixes the problem.